# Python replacing part of a string which varies

Tags: python

New to python just getting to grips with everything. I'm looking to replace part of a string I have recurring in my data. I suspect regex is going to be the answer but being so new to python I'm struggling a little to get this right.

My text example is this "PROD v2.0 - Test Window - App". What happens is as the developers introduce new windows, the PROD v2.0 changes to v3.0 and so on. What I would like to do is remove the entire first part and leave just "Test Window - App"

I've got a load of other things going on in the script I am using also so I would ideally be looking for assistance with where to place this.

Below is the script I have so far. I have removed certain aspects of this as this is for a work project and certain parts I cannot share. Any help would be massively appreciated, I am aware that my script may not be written as well as it could be, the project I am working on is due soon and I am just trying to get this functional at this stage.

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('REMOVED.xls', 'Sheet1', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('//REMOVED.csv', encoding='utf-8')

import codecs
import pandas as pd
import os
#import dataset
from datetime import datetime as dt

targetDir = 'REMOVED'
outputFile = 'UPLOADSTEP1.txt'

substitutions = COLUMN SUBS REMOVED               

selectCols = [COLUMN ORDER REMOVED]
first = True

# Set working directory
os.chdir(targetDir)

# Iterate thorugh all files in directory
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
if i.endswith('.csv') and i.startswith('Temp'):
    print (i);
    # Files are UTF-8 encoded with BOM which Pandas cannot handle. Open with         coedcs first before passing to Pandas
    opened = codecs.open(i, 'rU', 'UTF-8')
    # Read file into dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv(opened, header=0)

   # Replace headers
    for row in substitutions:
        if row[0] in df.columns:
            df.rename(columns={row[0]:row[1]}, inplace=True)
            print(row[0], '->', row[1])

    # Save to csv
    if first:
        # print("First section")
        # First file save, retain headers and overwrite previous
        # destFile = open(outputFile, 'w')
        df.to_csv(outputFile, columns=selectCols, header=True, index=False, low_memory=False, sep='\t')
        first = False
    else:
        # print("Subsequent section")
        # Not first file save, remove headers and append to previous
        destFile = open(outputFile, 'a')
        df.to_csv(destFile, columns=selectCols, header=False, index=False, low_memory=False, sep='\t')
    continue

# Symbol Cleanse
f1 = open('UPLOADSTEP1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('UPLOADSTEP2.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
f2.write(line.replace(' â€“ ', ' '))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that gives me a clue where the substitution would go.  But in general, I would probably use the `re` module.  Is it fair to say you would want to replace everything up to and including the first `- ` with nothing?

Comment: Yes sorry there is nothing in my code at present which relates to it as I am a bit lost as to what to put where. I'd like to get rid of the whole PROD and version number plus the hyphen. The text I want to remove just appears in certain columns in my data set. As I said the versions numbers constantly change so it would need to deal with that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is far from optimal, but should do the trick.

I'm assuming that all the strings that you are trying to replace start with "PROD vXXXX -" and that you dont have occurences of "PROD v" that you dont want to relace (or that dont match the previous pattern)

```
text = ''
with open(inputfilename,'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

while 'PROD v' in text:
    tail = text[text.find('PROD v'):]     # get the text after "PROD v"
    tail = tail[tail.find('-')+1:]        # get rid of everything before the nearest "-"
    text = text[:text.find('PROD v')] + tail

with open(outputfilename,'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: Yep that worked thank you very much! I need to try and refine my script overall now because with the file size I am dealing with it's taking a while to run but job done thanks!